# App crashes when launched in debugging on setUserVisibleHint()

Tags: android, android-fragments

If I ran the app normally it would work just fine,when I put a breakpoint on if statement in `setUserVisibleHint()`,it crashes with exception:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity`.

So what's gonna be the problem?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment 


public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static CommunityFragment newInstance() {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment     
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
}


@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

    if (getActivity() != null && isVisibleToUser) {
       // fragment is visible
        }
    } else if (getActivity() != null) {
       // fragment is invisible
        }
    }
  } 
}
```

logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          PID: 8669
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1578)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2883)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1268)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2177)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1244)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1080)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:971)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:95)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2143)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1979)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:626)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:786)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
                                                                             at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                             at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                            at android
```

Comment: Can you post the whole logcat?

Comment: parent class doesn't seems to be throw any exception 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)

Comment: @azizbekian I did :)

Comment: Are you placing a breakpoint on exactly the method declaration line or on any line within a method?

Comment: You can look this link.[https://github.com/xmagicj/LazyFragment/tree/master/app/src](https://github.com/xmagicj/LazyFragment/tree/master/app/src).Hope help you.

Comment: I placce it on if (getActivity() != null && isVisibleToUser),the debugger is triggered,I press  resume and the app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if (getActivity() != null && isVisibleToUser) {
       // fragment is visible
        }
    } else if (getActivity() != null) {
       // fragment is invisible
        }
```

try with

```
if (getView() != null) {
       // fragment is visible
        }
```

It worked for me.

Comment: same problem :(